# Measuring speed between Unix server and PC

Tags: unix, networking, performance

My company just purchased identical Unix servers to the ones we are currently using.  The new servers are going to be hosted about 1000 miles away in Langhorn, PA while the current servers are hosted locally.  Once the hosted servers are finished being set up, the local servers will be going away.  My boss asked me to try and find a tool that could help us determine how much longer it will take to move files from the server to our local PC for the local servers vs. the remote servers.

Does anyone know of a tool that could accomplish this?  Obviously I could just move a large file and use wall clock time, but depending on what is running on the server, I doubt this would be very accurate.

Thanks in advance!
Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Most FTP programs i've used show transfer times, FileZilla for example:

```
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 118,782,740 bytes in 11 seconds
```